# Convert Map of mutable Set of strings to Map of immutable set of strings in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a "dirtyMap" which is immutable.Map[String, collection.mutable.Set[String]]. I want to convert dirtyMap to immutable Map[String, Set[String]]. Could you please let me know how to do this. I tried couple of ways that didn't produce positive result

**Method 1: Using map function**

```
dirtyMap.toSeq.map(e => {
  val key = e._1
  val value = e._2.to[Set]
  e._1 -> e._2
}).toMap()
```

I'm getting syntax error

**Method 2: Using foreach**

```
dirtyMap.toSeq.foreach(e => {
  val key = e._1
  val value = e._2.to[Set]
  e._1 -> e._2
}).toMap()
```

cannot apply toMap to output of foreach

Disclaimer: I am a Scala noob if you couldn't tell.

UPDATE: Method 1 works when I remove parenthesis from  toMap() function. However, following is an elegant solution

```
dirtyMap.mapValues(v => v.toSet)
```

Thank you Gabriele for providing answer with a great explanation. Thanks Duelist and Debojit  for your answer as well

Comment: Also removing parentheses after `toMap` in **Method 1** could help to get rid of syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
dirtyMap.mapValues(_.toSet)
```

`mapValues` will apply the function to only the values of the `Map`, and `.toSet` converts a mutable `Set` to an immutable one.

(I'm assuming `dirtyMap` is a `collection.immutable.Map`. In case it's a mutable one, just add `toMap` in the end)

If you're not familiar with the underscore syntax for lambdas, it's a shorthand for:

```
dirtyMap.mapValues(v => v.toSet)
```

---

Now, your first example doesn't compile because of the `()`. `toMap` takes no explicit arguments, but it takes an implicit argument. If you want the implicit argument to be inferred automatically, just remove the `()`.

The second example doesn't work because `foreach` returns `Unit`. This means that `foreach` executes side effects, but it doesn't return a value. If you want to chain transformations on a value, never use `foreach`, use `map` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flatMap` for it:

```
dirtyMap.flatMap(entry => Map[String, Set[String]](entry._1 -> entry._2.toSet)).toMap
```

Firstly you `map` each entry to `immutable.Map(entry)` with updated entry, where value is `immutable.Set` now. Your map looks like this: mutable.Map.
And then `flatten` is called, so you get `mutable.Map` with each entry with `immutable.Set`. And then toMap converts this map to to immutable.

This variant is complicated a bit, you simply can use `dirtyMap.map(...).toMap` as Debojit Paul mentioned.

Another variant is `foldLeft`:

```
dirtyMap.foldLeft(Map[String, Set[String]]())(
  (map, entry) => map + (entry._1 -> entry._2.toSet)
)
```

You specify accumulator, which is `immutable.Map` and you add each entry to this map with converted Set.

As for me, I think using `foldLeft` is more effective way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

dirtyMap.map({case (k,v) => (k,v.toSet)})

Comment: It still returns `mutable.Map`. `toMap` is needed

Comment: `scala> dirtyMap.map({case (k,v) => (k,v.toSet)})
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]] = Map(a -> Set(3, 1, 2), b -> Set(3, 1, 2))`

Comment: Are you sure that your `dirtyMap` is `immutable`?

Comment: Try executing i dont know why you said it will return mutable map. Please share your output

Comment: `scala> val dirtyMap = new mutable.HashMap[String, collection.mutable.Set[String]] ()
dirtyMap: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]] = Map()


scala> dirtyMap update ("test1", collection.mutable.Set("test11", "test12"))


scala> dirtyMap update ("test2", collection.mutable.Set("test21", "test22"))


scala> dirtyMap.map({case (k,v) => (k,v.toSet)})
res2: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]] = Map(test2 -> Set(test21, test22), test1 -> Set(test12, test11))`

Comment: I specified mutable map as `mutable.HashMap` and after execution I got mutable.HashMap. Maybe you declared `dirtyMap` as `Map[String, Set[String]]`? If so, it is `immutable` by default.